# How to put spaces between vertically stacked buttons in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The following code properly places each button vertically stacked.

What is the way to insert spaces between them? Currently they are stuck to each other.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.buttonClass
{
    color: blue;
    background-color: yellow;
    
    display:block;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<button class="buttonClass">one</button>
<button class="buttonClass">two</button>
<button class="buttonClass">three</button>
<button class="buttonClass">four</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this => `margin: 0 0 1em;` on `.buttonClass`

Comment: Just add a margin.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: This question is not related to any flexbox.

Comment: the duplicate cover solutions without flexbox as well and provide more details on other possible best solutions you can use instead of using margin alone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't we use `margin`?

```css
.buttonClass
{
    color: blue;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="buttonClass">one</button>
    <button class="buttonClass">two</button>
    <button class="buttonClass">three</button>
    <button class="buttonClass">four</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to all this. Had forgotten about margins.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl No problem, and I'm new to this community. If it helped, can you accept the answer as well?

Comment: Acceptance requires a certain time period. I have done it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-bottom to put spaces between vertically stacked css buttons.

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>

.buttonClass
{
    color: blue;
    background-color: yellow;
    
    display:block;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<button class="buttonClass">one</button>
<button class="buttonClass">two</button>
<button class="buttonClass">three</button>
<button class="buttonClass">four</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Your first intuition would be to use padding-bottom but using padding on buttons increases the distance between the text.

It is a good practice to use padding on buttons instead of width and height.

```
You can use margin-bottom or padding-bottom to put spaces between vertically stacked css buttons.



 <html>
<head>
<style>

.buttonClass
{
    color: blue;
    background-color: yellow;
    
    display:block;
    padding-left: 12.5px;
  padding-right:12.5px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<button class="buttonClass">one</button>
<button class="buttonClass">two</button>
<button class="buttonClass">three</button>
<button class="buttonClass">four</button>

</body>
</html>
```